# Create buttons "Select all" and "Unselect all" in Plotly for R

Tags: r, plotly, data-visualization

Plotly graphs have all series selected by default, and it allows me to unselect them (and then select them again) only one by one.

Is there an approach that allows me to unselect or select them all like an Excel filter would do?

I have found the following [solution for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57855912/plotly-with-python-line-chart-deselect-all), but I don't know how to implement it in R.

Comment: if you click twice on the legend it should work, doesn't it?

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Maybe it's because I am using a local HTML file, which I have created using the "Export -> Save as webpage" option from RStudio? I need the file as a local HTML.